# Excel full screen mode cant write to cell

Tags: vba, excel, fullscreen

I have a problem with excel in full screen mode. When I chose another sheet (via macro) and go back to previous sheet (via macro) I cant write something to cell selected cell. Any advice?

My code for fullscreen:

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
Application.CommandBars("Full Screen").Visible = False
End Sub
```

My macro code for select sheet:

```
Private Sub skok()
Sheets("Sheet 2").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you handling other events for workbook and worksheet ? Do you get any errors?

Comment: No errors only I cant write to cell... Full screen is for workbook and macro in worksheet for switching

Comment: You will have to post more code - IMO it  is not possible to reliably reproduce your issue with what you have currently posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can testify that this problem is happening to my workbook also!

To improve visibility, I make the workbook go fullscreen with the DisplayFullscreen=True in the same sub.

Later, the user can move to Sheets 2 with macro in a command button. On sheet 2 there is a button "Save & Return" which runs a macro like

```
Sheets("Sheet1").select
```

But when we return to Sheet1 the cells seem to freeze. But the command buttons still work.The situation can be 'unlocked' when I randomly select another sheet below on the sheet tab. Then returning to Sheet1 I can then enter in the cells!

One strange thing is that although the sheet seem freeze, I can still copy & paste text in a cell using the Ctrl+C & Ctrl+V on keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, and **it is an Excel bug**! We can still copy/paste values in cells, write in cells by VBA code, but we cannot *edit* cells' value anymore by double-clicking the cell (or F2). The cell edition is frozen! (It is like unchecking the option "Allow editing directly in cells" (Options->Advanced options-> (Sector)"Editing options".)

To create the bug:
Click on an ActiveX control while you are in full screen mode (Application.DisplayFullScreen = True)
...and the bug is there now you cannot edit cells anymore!

The bug stays as long as the formula bar is not physically visible on your screen (fullScreen or not) and will STOP (as long as you do not recreate the bug...) as soon as the formula bar is displayed (staying in fullScreen and executing "Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True" won't work)

The bug will "temporarily" stop (with hidden formula bar) if you activate another sheet but will start again if you click on any other ActiveX control in any sheets (fullScreen or not)...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a good lesson in form.  Try to avoid `.Activate` and `.Select`.  If you always specify your ranges you can avoid situations like this with multiple workbooks.  Use the format:

```
Workbooks("myBook.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "whatever"
```

or:

```
with Workbooks("myBook.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("A1").Value = "A"
    .Range("A2").Value = 2
    .Range("A3").Value = "Blah"
End With
```

Comment: No problem with code but with visible full screen if I have fullscreen and switch between sheets via macro now cant write. But when I have excel in normal view is it possible write to cell and everything works normal.

Comment: @FiínekCahů I may be worng, but I imagine that the code loses focus on the workbook once you maximise the application.  Try adding the first line of code into yours, specifying the workbook and sheet (obviously with the names of your sheet/workbook).  If it doesn't print "Whatever" to A1 I'm wrong, and will delete this answer